# Best, free web3 tutorials? Basically how to learn building dapps

Tags: contract-development, tokens, nft, dapp-development, tutorials

What are other resources ppl really like? Would love to learn what else is out there, particularly the free ones.

[Edit] Adding a few of the most popular below:

- [Ethereum.org's NFT series](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/how-to-mint-an-nft/?a=18798bffa0) -- you'll learn how to write and deploy a smart contract, mint a NFT, and view your NFTs in a wallet
- [Hello world tutorial](https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/hello-world-smart-contract/?a=18798bffa0) -- you'll learn about Metamask, Hardhat, and Solidity (core web3 tech stack) in this beginner tutorial
- [Patrick Collins's OG Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyMwXuJrbJQ/?a=18798bffa0) -- this is a 30+ hour course on web3
- [Alchemy University](https://university.alchemy.com/?a=18798bffa0) -- this is free series of courses that will take anyone who's just starting out, to being able to build a dapp from end-to-end. At the end, you'll be able to add "AU" in the education section of your Linkedin
- [Road to Web3 series](https://www.web3.university/tracks/road-to-web3/?a=18798bffa0) -- this is a free 10 part series that builds a different dapp each class. Each part takes about 30 min to 1 hour
- [Concise Hardhat tutorials](https://dev.to/yakult/a-concise-hardhat-tutorial-part-1-7eo/?a=18798bffa0) -- this covers the basis of using Hardhat to deploy a ERC20 token contact and a ERC721 contract (NFT)
- [Deploy a Smart Contract with Remix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0k3Jwu880s/?a=18798bffa0) -- Chainlink covers how to use Remix (an IDE) in deploying a basic smart contract

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, one of the best resources you have to learn how to code DApps in Ethereum is [DApp University YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/@DappUniversity).

You can find a lot of very useful playlists there.

It also offers a paid course to build a DEX from scratch, which is really up-to-date with the latest tools and libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that Smart Contract Programmer on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/@smartcontractprogrammer) wasn't mentioned yet. He makes short videos to a really specific topic that have extremely good explainations. Usually, people get it first try. All of his videos are completely free and he is also the creator of soliditybyexample.com that provides the code snippets of his videos in text/blog format. There are also [challenges](https://www.smartcontract.engineer/challenges) with video explainations he made.

He is one of the few that also teach **security and vulnerabilty prevention**.